# How many permutations $(a_i)_{i=1}^{30}$ of $\{1,\dots,30\}$ satisfy $m$ divides $a_{n+m}-a_n$ when $m \in \{2,3,5\}$ and $1 \le n<n+m \le 30$?

Tags: permutations

Define a permutation $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{30})$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,30\}$ as *good* if for all $m \in \{2,3,5\}$, we have that $m$ divides $a_{n+m}-a_n$ for all integers $n$ satisfying $1 \leq n < n+m \leq 30$.  How many good permutations are there?

I don't understand how to formulate the binomial expressions and casework. Could someone provide me with a solution? Thank you.

Comment: The question is getting votes to close as unclear; I've reworded it with the intention to make it clearer.  But please [edit] if I've blundered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  the condition on $m=2$ says either all the even numbers are in even positions or all the even numbers are in odd positions.  What does $a_1 \bmod 3$ imply?  How about $a_1 \bmod 5$?

Comment: I understand that the there is a bijection between the indices and the corresponding numbers moduli, however do you mind providing a solution, as I still can't get much further. Thank you.